# Create gigabit bond from 2x100Mbps ethernet

Tags: network, catalina

I followed the instructions from: [Combine Ethernet ports into a virtual port on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2798/mac) to create a bind between two 100Mbps Ethernet interfaces.

However the bond itself is only a 100Mbps interface. It there a way to make a Gigabit bonded interface to get 200Mbps out of the two interfaces at once?

Comment: On the aggregated interface are you setting it to auto negotiate or did you fix it at 100 MB?  The latter would explain a local thing you can change. The former needs you to work on the switch and not the Mac.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [link aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation).

First off, to bond two Ethernet ports together, your *switch* must also support this and have the ports configured to do so.  From your description of things, it appears this part was overlooked because you still only have a 100MB connection.

Secondly, you can’t get a gigabit link (1Gb) from two 100MB connections. 1Gb = 1000Mb.  Two 100Mb links aggregated is 200Mb.

Comment: Also: it would be simpler to just buy a 1000MB adapter as they're cheaply available < £15 on Amazon for example and any cheap CAT6 cable will do gigabit, and most CAT5e will do a fairly reasonable job.

Comment: @unknowndomain - that is most definitely true and I'm glad you mentioned it.  I just don't want to discount the the experience factor of learning how to do this.  I've done (and still do) overly complex scenarios where a purchase off of Amazon or eBay was significantly more cost effective, but I gained a valuable skill instead.

Comment: agreed ethernet bonding is something I have no experience of presently, but someone with a Synology NAS or similar with multiple ports would benefit from the speed increase this would give them for example.